# Eclipse Indigo, Glassfish 3.1.1 plugin debug issue

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, glassfish-3

I have migrated from myeclipse to eclipse and started using the open source glassfish plugin with the new version of glassfish server. It was not smooth sailing but I am up and running. My question is when I start the glassfish server on the debug mode, and make changes to a java file, it restarts the whole app which does not make me happy.

In the myeclipse world, it would do the exploded deployment and I will be able to correct the code and keep on debugging and working without restarting the app. That's of course myeclipse 8.6 and glassfish v2.

Am I missing something or is this functionality only provided by myeclipse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Eclipse-controlled servers, if you publish the application in Eclipse to your server, Eclipse keeps track of changes to Java code and automatically redeploys the app upon change.  I never do this for the reason you are experiencing.

If you just point your Glassfish server configuration at your application so that it functions as an application deployment directory (this can be done with JBoss, not sure about Glassfish), Eclipse is no longer monitoring changes and will not auto-redeploy.  I'm able to make changes to Java classes while the server is running and about 75% my changes are picked up.

Another option would be to use a tool which purports to allow you to make any and all Java changes without recompiling, like [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/), which works in Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks so that means NO hotswap other than the method you are referencing. I will go with that. I am trying netbeans with gf integration to see how it will work. I believe I can make glassfish to point to my classes, not sure what the best method is. If not, I might just go back to myeclipse since it causes a lot of slowdown in my work.